# The method is not being called. I think maybe something with a parameter?

Tags: c#

`WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1.BankAccount` does not contain a definition for `withBox` and no extension method `withBox` accepting a first argument of type `WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1.BankAccount` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is one the `num1 = Convert.ToDecimal(this.withBox.Text);` line of code.

Earlier I asked a question about this, and did much more research into my problems. I believed I did everything correct this time. But still getting errors. I am unsure of what I am doing wrong now.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BankAccount a = new BankAccount();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        decimal iBa = 300.00m;
        this.aMtBox.Text = iBa.ToString();
    }
    private void dep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            decimal num1 = 0.00m;
            decimal iBa = 300.00m;
            num1 = Convert.ToDecimal(this.depBox.Text);
            decimal total = num1 + iBa;
            this.aMtBox.Text = total.ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR", "Oops, this isn't good!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
    public void withdrawl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.aMtBox.Text = a.Balance.ToString();
    }

    public class BankAccount
    {
        decimal balance;
        decimal iBa;
        decimal num1;

        public decimal Balance
        {
            get {return balance;}
        }
        public decimal IBa
        {
            get {return iBa;}
        }
        public decimal Num1
        {
            get {return num1;}
        }

        public BankAccount()
        {
            iBa = 300.00m;
            num1 = Convert.ToDecimal(this.withBox.Text);
            balance = iBa - num1;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: In the context it's being used, `this` refers to an instance of `BankAccount`. `BankAccount` doesn't have a `withBox`. It's probably in `InitializeComponent`. But all that said, a `BankAccount` instance is not inherently tied to it's "parent" `Form1` just because you instantiate it there. What if you, in `static void Main()`, do `new Form1.BankAccount()` 100 times (note: you won't create 100 forms)? What do you expect `this` to be?

Comment: you did not define `withBox` at all

Comment: At any rate, instantiating `BankAccount` as part of constructing `Form1` is way too early to meaningfully use `withBox.Text`.

Comment: withbox is actually private void withBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){} Im sorry I didnt post that early. As I hadnt clicked it open yet I knew its name by the properties

Answer (score 2):

You are using `this.WithBox.Text` within the `BankAccount` where this property is not defined. I guess this is a defined within `Form1`.

You should change your `BankAccount` constructor to something like this

```
public BankAccount(decimal number)
{
    iBa = 300.00m;
    num1 = number;
    balance = iBa - num1;
}
```

and then create the `BankAccount` passing the value in the form this way:

```
BankAccount a = null;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    decimal iBa = 300.00m;
    this.aMtBox.Text = iBa.ToString();
    a = new BankAccount(Convert.ToDecimal(this.withBox.Text));
}
```

Maybe it doesn't have much sense to get the value from `withBox` at the form initialization, don't have the context of the app, but you will get the idea. Another approach is to set the property for Num1 to the `BankAccount` whereas necessary.

Comment: `withBox.Text` is likely going to be a `string` not an `int`. I suspect the right solution looks something like either a) don't make `BankAccount` until you need it or b) `new BankAccount(calculateBalance: () => Int32.Parse(this.withBox.Text))`

Comment: It is a string... im testing something out.

Comment: Well, with that update, it asked me if I wanted to submit something to microsoft with an error update. That was strange. I clicked yes.

Comment: It's likely that `Convert.ToDecimal(this.withBox.Text)` is throwing an exception. `""` is not a string representation of a decimal number.

Comment: Just be sure not passing an empty string to the bank account or as @ta.speot.is said, don't make BankAccount until you need it, it seems you are only using it on withdrawl_Click.